# How to add Validators like Reactive Forms for Another Model Data

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

**Model.ts**

```
export class Model{
    name:string;
    phone:number;
}
```

**registration.ts**

```
import {Model} from './Model.ts';

export class RegistrationComponent{

    ngOnInit(){
        public objModel:Model;
    }
    saveClick(){

    }
}
```

**registration.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="objModel.name" />
<input type="phone" [(ngModel)]="objModel.phone" />
<button (click)="saveClick()">Save</button>
```

I am creating a form with external model control using [(ngModel)]. How can i add Validation like required, minlength like Reactive Forms/Model Driven forms approach in angular 2. Is it right i am doing.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).

Use `[formGroup]="myForm"`. It'll be possible to submit a request only if the validators for each field are satisfied. The latter are linked via `formControlName`. The button will be disable until all the validators are satisfied.

**registration.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <p class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Name</label>
        <input
                id="name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                formControlName="name"
                value=""
                class="form-control"
        />
        <span class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid name.
        </span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
        <input
                id="telephone"
                type="text"
                name="telephone"
                formControlName="telephone"
                value=""
                class="form-control"
        />
        <span class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid telephone number.
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid"
                translate
        >Sign In</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**registration.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export interface Model {
    name?: string;
    telephone?: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-registration-form',
    templateUrl: './registration.component.html'
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

    registrationForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (
            this.registrationForm === undefined ||
            this.registrationForm === null
        ) {
            this.registrationForm = new FormGroup( {
                name: new FormControl('', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)),
                telephone:new FormControl('', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1))
            });
        }
    }

    onSubmit() {

        if ( this.registrationForm.valid ) {

            const formValue = this.registrationForm.value;

            const model: Model = {
                name: formValue.name,
                telephone: formValue.telephone
            };

            console.log('model', model);
        }
    }

}
```

You can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You can use any kind of validators, you can also build yours. For instance, you could apply a regex to your telephone number to understand if the input is a valid one using `Validators.Pattern('yourRegxTelephonePattern')`.